# insertBefore is adding the earlier messges

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a Javascript that displays content in a `div` when a link is clicked. the code is as below.

The scenario is like this, I've 10 anchor tags and when I click on a anchor it should display the result in a div `textResult`

```
function getTheIncident(keyWord, text, shortDesc, description) {
    console.log(keyWord + "\t" + text);
    var e = document.getElementById('textResult');
    var issueTag = document.createElement('H2');
    var resolutionTag = document.createElement('H2');
    var descTag = document.createElement('H2');

    if (text) {
        var issue = document.createElement('div');
        issueTag.innerHTML = "Issue";
        issue.innerHTML = shortDesc.replace('\^', '\'');
        issue.insertBefore(issueTag, issue.firstChild);

        var resol = document.createElement('div');
        resolutionTag.innerHTML = "Resolution";
        resol.innerHTML = text.replace('\^', '\'');
        resol.insertBefore(resolutionTag, resol.firstChild);

        var desc = document.createElement('div');
        descTag.innerHTML = "Description";
        desc.innerHTML = description.replace('\^', '\'');
        desc.insertBefore(descTag, desc.firstChild);

        e.insertBefore(resol, e.firstChild);
        e.insertBefore(desc, e.firstChild);
        e.insertBefore(issue, e.firstChild);

    }
    else {

        h1Tag.innerHTML = "Issue";
        e.innerHTML = shortDesc.replace('\^', '\'');
        e.insertBefore(h1Tag, e.firstChild);

        h1Tag.innerHTML = "Description";
        e.innerHTML = shortDesc.replace('\^', '\'');
        e.insertBefore(h1Tag, e.firstChild);

        h1Tag.innerHTML = "No Resolution Available";
        e.innerHTML = text.replace('\^', '\'');
        e.insertBefore(h1Tag, e.firstChild);
    }
}
```

here for the first time when I click I get the result as below.

```
Issue

Laptop issue
Description

RAM with 128GB
Resolution

A Procurement order has been placed for a new RAM with 128 GB
```

and when I click it for second time

```
Issue

Laptop issue
Description

RAM with 128GB
Resolution

A Procurement order has been placed for a new RAM with 128 GB
Issue

Laptop issue
Description

RAM with 128GB
Resolution

A Procurement order has been placed for a new RAM with 128 GB
```

But I want this to come up only once.

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

**Note** I'm using Javascript, not using any jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `insertBefore()` if you don't want to insert additional content?

Comment: *But I want this to come up only once* Do you mean if you double click on button it should come once, of it should check for duplicate values and process accordingly?

Comment: @Rajesh I want to clear what ever was there in `textResult` and show the new content... .

Comment: You can do that as `textResult.innerHTML = ''`

Comment: @stephen.vakil I'm getting result and passing it as parameters to this function and then creating tags and adding the content to `textResult`

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the old children before adding the new ones, otherwise you are going to have both at the same time.

```
 var issue, resol, desc;
 if (text) {
    if (issue) e.removeChild(issue);
    if (resol) e.removeChild(resol);
    if (desc) e.removeChild(desc)
    issue = document.createElement('div');
    issueTag.innerHTML = "Issue";
    issue.innerHTML = shortDesc.replace('\^', '\'');
    issue.insertBefore(issueTag, issue.firstChild);

    resol = document.createElement('div');
    resolutionTag.innerHTML = "Resolution";
    resol.innerHTML = text.replace('\^', '\'');
    resol.insertBefore(resolutionTag, resol.firstChild);

    desc = document.createElement('div');
    descTag.innerHTML = "Description";
    desc.innerHTML = description.replace('\^', '\'');
    desc.insertBefore(descTag, desc.firstChild);

    e.insertBefore(resol, e.firstChild);
    e.insertBefore(desc, e.firstChild);
    e.insertBefore(issue, e.firstChild);

 }
```

This can not be the best solution